# Date is not getting properly bound in my textbox Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, json, oracle, date

I want to show my date field in a textbox which is coming from `Oracle` database.

The scenario is, my date stored in DB column is `01-12-17` and its datatype is `date`.

and while binding it is coming as `1-11-17` I don't know why it's happening like this.

Here is my binding code.

```
if (getJSONValue.LAUNCH_DATE != "" || getJSONValue.LAUNCH_DATE != null) {
    var newDate = new Date(getJSONValue.LAUNCH_DATE);
    var day = newDate.getDate();
    var month = newDate.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    var year = newDate.getFullYear();
    $('#txtLaunchDate').val(day + "-" + ((month)) + "-" + year.toString().substr(-2));
}
else {
    $('#txtLaunchDate').val("");
}
```

Comment: getJSONValue.LAUNCH_DATE = ?

Comment: Try putting a paranthesis for (newDate.getUTCMonth() + 1)

Comment: @javaguy: i get as `2017-12-01T00:00:00`

Comment: @Beginner: let me try and check

Comment: @Beginner: I still get month as 11 only

Answer (score 0):

When you call this :

```
 var newDate = new Date(getJSONValue.LAUNCH_DATE);// if your date is 01-12-2017
```

the result is : Thu Jan 12 2017 00:00:00

It switches month and day info.

And as you try to add two values it contatenates :

```
var month = newDate.getUTCMonth() + 1; //returns 1 + 1 as string and the result is 11.
```

That that is why you see 1-11-17.

If you want a simple solution,

```
        var str = getJSONValue.LAUNCH_DATE; //"01-12-2017"; 
        var array = str.split("-");
        var day = array[0];
        var month = array[1];
        var year = array[2].substr(2);

        var dateStr = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getMonth` instead of `getUTCMonth`:

```js
    var newDate = new Date('2017-12-01T00:00:00');
    var day = newDate.getDate();
    var month = newDate.getMonth()+1;
    var year = newDate.getFullYear();
    alert(day + "-" + ((month)) + "-" + year.toString().substr(-2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: perfect.. will it work for other date scenarios which can cause issues

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var month = (Number(newDate.getUTCMonth()) + 1);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.